# ActiveStorage: Old urls still request deprecated :combine_options in variation_key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

Recently I upgraded from Rails 6.0.3.4 to 6.1.3. ActiveStorage deprecated `combine_options`, which I cleared from my app. All fresh request work as expected.
Internet Bots (Facebook, Google, ...) cache urls to images hosted on a website (like mine). According to my Rollbar records they request these a couple of times a day.

The cached URL's that should load ActiveStorage attachments include an old `variation_key` in the URL. When the blob wants to load using the decoded `variation_key`, I see that `combine_options` is still present. This throws a `500 Internal Server Error with ArgumentError (Active Storage's ImageProcessing transformer doesn't support :combine_options, as it always generates a single ImageMagick command.):`.

Is there any way I can stop these errors from showing up?

Rails version: 6.1.3.
Ruby version: 2.7.2p137

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this issue using some middleware. This will intercept all incoming requests, scan if they are `ActiveStorage` urls, find the ones with the deprecated `combine_options` and just return 404 not found. This code will also raise an error is the current environment is development, this way I don't accidentally introduce the deprecated code again.

For those of you who might have the same problem, here's the code.

application.rb

```rb
require_relative '../lib/stopper'
config.middleware.use ::Stopper
```

lib/stopper.rb

```rb
class Stopper
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)

    req = Rack::Request.new(env)
    path = req.path

    if problematic_active_storage_url?(path)
      if ENV["RACK_ENV"] == 'development'
        raise "Problematic route, includes deprecated combine_options"
      end
      [404, {}, ['not found']]
    else
      @app.call(env)
    end
  end

  def problematic_active_storage_url?(path)
    if active_storage_path?(path) && !valid_variation_key?(variation_key_from_path(path))
      return true
    end
    false
  end

  def active_storage_path?(path)
    path.start_with?("/rails/active_storage/representations/")
  end

  def variation_key_from_path(path)
    if path.start_with?("/rails/active_storage/representations/redirect/")
      path.split('/')[6]
    elsif path.start_with?("/rails/active_storage/representations/")
      path.split('/')[5]
    end
  end

  def valid_variation_key?(var_key)
    if decoded_variation = ActiveStorage::Variation.decode(var_key)
      if transformations = decoded_variation.transformations
        if transformations[:combine_options].present?
          return false
        end
      end
    end
    true
  end
end
```

Comment: I've implemented this code, and it removes the error, but does not trigger a new image? It just returns no image?

Comment: I would need to see your code as I have implemented this exact code and it works.

Comment: Hi Yoko, thank you for your reply. I've done a 1:1 implementation. And since you wrote this, i have given the failing images a second look, and I was apparently suffering from 2 different errors. Your code works  Thank you!

Comment: @Tobias Haha no problem, I've had that problem many times  Glad I could help!

Comment: While this works and we have used it. Will we ever be able to remove this? Can we add something to an active storage controller to strip the :combine_options key?

Comment: Could we monkey patch this? Id rather touch this specific method than every single request. https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.1.4/activestorage/lib/active_storage/transformers/image_processing_transformer.rb#L32

Comment: @JohnPollard Maybe you could submit an issue on the Rails GitHub page?

Comment: It seems like an intentional change if you want the changes they've made to the transformer class. They first deprecated it, and now they don't allow it. But for applications like ours, it makes it difficult to know what is an actual error and whats not since it raises a 500 error. I believe they should have it deprecated for a longer time period.

Answer (score 1):

I thought the stopper was a great solution but eventually I wanted to get rid of it. Unforunately most of our old requests were stilling coming through months later and no one was honoring the 404s. So I decided to monkey patch based off the previous rails versions. This is was I did.

config/initalizers/active_storage.rb

```
Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
  require 'active_storage'
   
    ActiveStorage::Transformers::ImageProcessingTransformer.class_eval do
      private
        def operations
          transformations.each_with_object([]) do |(name, argument), list|
            if name.to_s == "combine_options"
              list.concat argument.keep_if { |key, value| value.present? and key.to_s != "host" }.to_a
            elsif argument.present?
              list << [ name, argument ]
            end
          end
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for this! Will try to implement it soon.

Comment: Not sure if you need the host param but we needed to add it.